# nginx rewrite URL

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I want to rewrite the following URL:

```
index.php?SOMETHING=VALUE
```

As

```
/SOMETHING/VALUE
```

I'm inexperienced with nginx rewrites so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is `SOMETHING` a fixed value ? If not, how do you want to handle unexpected request such as `index.php?SOMETHING=VALUE&anotherField=foo` ?

Comment: Something is a variable and value is also a variable. There are no other variables in the URL

Comment: OK, thanks for your reply. You said that there *should not be* any other variable in the URL, but do you have full authority on the HTTP clients that will send you the requests ? I mean, if the requests come from any WWW user, there's a high probability that you will get some requests filled with third-party variables. Anyway, I will try to find an answer for only one variable.

Comment: I understand that. Can it be done though?

Comment: Perhaps you might get more answers if you post this question on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a solution to your problem :

```
location /index.php {
    if ( $args ~ "(?<PATH1>.*)=(?<PATH2>.*)" ) {
        rewrite ^ /${PATH1}/${PATH2}? last;
    }
}
```

Explanations:

- `if ( $args ~ "(?<PATH1>.*)=(?<PATH2>.*)" )` : captures the two relevant sections from the URL parameter, storing the values in variables `PATH1` and `PATH2`
- `rewrite ^` means "rewrite the entire URI"
- `/${PATH1}/${PATH2}` is constructing the new URI
- the trailing `?` informs `nginx` that you don't want to append the original URL parameters
- `last` tells `nginx` to continue to follow rules after the rewrite

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the exact URI you are using as a request, and the exact URI you intended it to be rewritten to. Also, is the final location a static file or a PHP-based location ?